# mod_rewrite RewriteRule takes priority over Redirect in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have two different kinds of rules in my `.htaccess` file. The first group matches on exact files, and then I have a generic catch-all for everything else. I have read you can use the `[L]` for rewrite rules, but is there an equivalent for `Redirect 301`?  For example, my `.htaccess` file looks like this:

```
Redirect 301 /exact_page.html http: //www.newsite.com/new_page1.html

Redirect 301 /some_other_page.html http ://www.newsite.com/new_page2.html

RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.newsite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

What I would like is for pages `exact_page.html` and `some_other_page.html` to be redirected exactly as shown, and everything else gets maps from the domain to the new domain, with the rest of the url intact.  Instead, it looks to me like the first two `Redirect 301`'s are being ignored, or more precisely, are being superseded by the final rule.  Is there a way to tell apache to stop after it finds the first match?

Answer (score 1):

I think something like this should work:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(exact_page\.html|some_other_page\.html)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.newsite.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^exact_page\.html$ http://www.newsite.com/new_page1.html [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^some_other_page\.html$ http://www.newsite.com/new_page2.html [R=301,L]
```

Comment: The problem is I have something like 500 pages that need specific handling. Can I just do RewriteRules for each of the 500 pages, using [L], and then do the generic re-write afterwards? I thought if I put the [L] on the exact page matches that it would work. I was hoping there was an equivalent with Redirect 301

Comment: Redirect 301 is not a part of mod rewrite, so you cannot use the L flag with that.

Comment: Btw you can use your Redirect 301 commands and the same RewriteCond with your generic rule. It won't interfere anything... It was just easier for me to use RewriteRule for anything.

Comment: RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} !=301
Try this condition too, maybe the Redirect 301 changes the redirect status, so you won't have to write every single page in the condition...